# how to use Comma Seperator in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 4 columns one has `id` and other columns `(A,B,C)` has binary values.

I want the results like, columns`(A,B,C)` which has `value = 1`.Then particular Column name must be displayed in new column(D) with comma separated values.

I want the results like below. Can anyone please help me?

```
Id A B C D
1  1 1 0 A,B 
2  0 1 0 B
3  0 1 0 B
4  1 0 1 A,C
5  1 0 1 A,C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `CASE` expression will do it:

```
SELECT *,
    D = 
        STUFF((
            CASE
                WHEN A = 1 THEN ',A'
                ELSE ''
            END + 
            CASE
                WHEN B = 1 THEN ',B'
                ELSE ''
            END + 
            CASE
                WHEN C = 1 THEN ',C'
                ELSE ''
            END 
        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM tbl
```

Comment: Thanks Felix.This is what im looking for .